# Exchange Managed Availability

Tags: exchange, monitoring, exchange-2013

I have Exchange Server 2013 SP1 installed on Win Server 2012. I am developing an Exchange Monitoring tool.

I am not able to view all HealthSets in Managed Availability. I have tried below commands:

```
Get-HealthReport -Identity localhost -HealthSet Antimalware 
Get-ServerHealth -Identity localhost -HealthSet Antimalware
```

How can we enable all HealthSets. Is there a way to simulated the states of these HealthSets ?

Answer (score 0):

Exchange 2013 SP1 is very old, therefore I would suggest you start by updating the server to the latest build - CU10 or 11.

Both of those commands work for me on the latest build. Do you have the antimalware tools enabled?